# Num Threads trade-off in non-parallelizable work

Tags: gpgpu, hlsl, compute-shader, directcompute

I've been a good boy and parallelized my compute shader to execute 955 threads for 20 iterations

```c
[numthreads(955, 1, 1)]
void main( uint3 pos : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    ...
    for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
        //read from and write to groupshared memory
    }
}
```

But this isn't going to work out (because the parallelization introduces a realtime delay) so I have to do it a less parallel way. The easy way to approach the problem is to have 20 threads doing 955 iterations each

```c
[numthreads(20, 1, 1)]
void main( uint3 pos : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    ...
    for (uint i = 0; i < 955; i++)
    {
        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
        //read from and write to groupshared memory
    }
}
```

However, I can't reason about how this is going to perform (probably terribly).

I under this new approach I must keep the number iterations the same, but can trade off the frequency which I call the compute shader with the number of threads. Which gives me two options:

- Increase `20 -> 32` to have a full warp.
- Increase `20 -> 32 * n` to have warps running in parallel.

Maybe accessing groupshared memory is very cheap and so I don't have a performance problem in the first place.

Maybe I should try to optimize this on the cpu (I've already tried unoptimized and the performance was less than desired).

Comment: You don't really tell what type of algorithm you trying to achieve, so it's gonna be near impossible to give any advice here. A lot of serial ish algorithm have efficient gpu implementations, but the techniques are on a case per case basis.

Comment: @mrvux [dynamic time warping](https://riptutorial.com/dynamic-programming/example/25780/introduction-to-dynamic-time-warping) it involves a maximum of three values and then addition. You can parallelize it by going diagonal by diagonal, the hard part then is indexing. Anyway I would eventually need to readback the result to the cpu anyway so simd makes more sense, although debugging/iterating requires re-uploading to draw in realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone commented on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861869/11998382)

> To be specific, a single-thread group will generally cap utilization to around 3-6%. Dispatching only one group compounds the issue, capping utilization to well under 1%. Sticking to 256 threads with power-of-two dimension sizes is a good rule of thumb, and you should dispatch at least 2048 or so threads total to keep the hardware busy.

and I decided that doing this work on the gpu is a stupid thing to do. It's always best to look for robust solutions.

The rubust solution for my problem is to use SIMD, which I will have to now learn the hard way.

Comment: I'm going to use [xsimd](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd)